# Moving Wordpress with Super Skeleton theme

Tags: themes

I have a Wordpress with the Super Skeleton theme (http://themeforest.net/item/super-skeleton-wp-responsive-minimal-beautiful/647570) installed on my server. Now I want to move it to another server.

I have gone through the usual steps of moving a Wordpress and the Wordpress itself works great, but for some reason the settings for the Super Skeleton theme didn't seem to follow along in the move.

I have tried hitting the "Realod XML" button in the Theme Options without any success.

Comment: You didn't detail the "usual steps". Did you do a full dump and reload of the old database? If you did, and it still doesn't work, it's probably best to talk to the theme authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme is using Option Tree to save the theme options and this is the steps I went through to export the options from the old Wordpress installation and import them into the new one.

1. Go to `Users > Your profile` and check the checkbox in the bottom saying `Show Settings & Docs` under the `Options Tree` headline and hit `Update`.
2. This will enable a new item in the sidebar called `OptionTree` then go to `Settings > Export`
3. Follow the instructions on this page

I then did the exact same thing on the new Wordpress installation to import the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Install *and activate* your Theme on the new server
2. (Optional) Export/Import Theme options, either via the Theme itself (if the Theme provides options export/import), or by copying the Theme's entry, *and* the `{themename}_theme_mods` entry, in the `wp_options` DB table, and then importing to the new server. Doing this manually will require direct SQL access, e.g. using PHPMyAdmin)
3. Export site content from the old server, using WordPress exporter
4. Import site content to the new server, using WordPress importer

It appears that **Step 2** is where you're having a problem. Unfortunately, that step is largely out-of-scope for WPSE. And since you're using a commercial Theme, we don't have access to the Theme to be able to guide you with respect to what exact `wp_options` table entries to look for in a manual export/import.